# Home page doesn't update when publishing to IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application developed in ASP.NET and published in IIS. I changed the homepage on the properties screen ("Project" -> "Web" -> "Start Action" -> "Specific Page"), but when I publish and test it, it still points to my previously defined home page. I tried re-publishing it several times and restarting the server, but no luck.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's just the page that Visual Studio opens when you hit F5.

If you want the homepage of your site to change, change the view that's returned from `HomeController.Index()`, or change `Views/Home/Index.cshtml` to display what you want, or change the routing to another controller/action to display by default.

Answer (score 0):

check for RouteConfig.cs file in that you can put name of action and controller which you want to open first when your application will start.

check below image for reference.

[image]